# Visual studio code and Python - Install nuget package (.netcore) from private source with credentials

Tags: python, .net-core

does anyone else already tried to add some nuget package (.net core) in python project? Currently, I have a private url (which my package is residing) and I need to use that package to my python project.

[Project Structure][1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/44CKe.png

[requirements.txt][1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NUVmE.png

**Things I already tried:**

1. Tried to put the Python files in a solution, then right click and Manage Nuget Package (with error "Not Supported") - using VS 2019
2. Tried to pip install -r requirements.txt. No error but the package is not installed.
3. Tried to add NuGet.config in root folder of the project but the package source is not displaying in the dropdown. Here is the sample:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/k7bDd.png
4. Tried to add the private url (where my package is residing) in Nuget Gallery. Which is this case, my custom package source is displayed in the dropdown: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nDxoN.png
   But the problem is, I'm not sure where the credential should be added (for me to be able to connect to my private source).

**Other questions**

1. Does the CredentialProvider.Microsoft.exe can solve the credentials in the said private source? If yes, how can I implement this? I've search some solutions for this but can't find any that is working. Here it is https://i.stack.imgur.com/kBsFh.png
2. Is it possible to just download the nuget package locally and manually install it? If yes, do you know guys some documents that I can read about this?

Thanks guys.

Comment: Please ask only one question per question!

Comment: Do you have any answers to these questions??